# How to install Pip with VisualStudio Code Linux Terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, visual-studio-code

I've trying to use pip, I use visual studio code with a Linux Terminal. I have Python 3.10.4 installed. The way I installed pip was with

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

but when I try to check the version i get the following error:

> pip
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/bin/pip", line 11, in 
> load_entry_point('pip==20.0.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 490, in load_entry_point
> return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2854, in load_entry_point
> return ep.load()
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2445, in load
> return self.resolve()
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py", line 2451, in resolve
> module = **import**(self.module_name, fromlist=['**name**'], level=0)
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in 
> from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in 
> from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in 
> from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 19, in 
> from distutils.util import strtobool
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'

any clues on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try the update first :

```
> sudo apt update
```

And also, please provide which OS distribution you are using, the commands may change for `Ubuntu - Debian - Fedora ...`

Answer (score 0):

1. After opening the official [website of pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/), click "installation"
2. After entering the installation page, right-click "get-pip.py" and select "copy link address".

[image]

3. Enter `"wget + the address of the replication"` in Linux.
4. After downloading, execute the command Python get pip py.

You can refer to this [page](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/) for more details.